# how do I list and classify the items that do not exist in the table

Tags: sql

I run into road block and here is my issue:

I have a table, let's call it Items where all the items in my catalog are listed.
I have ItemSold where it lists each item sold on which day.
I have another table called Sales where it has the dates I want to enquiry about.

This is my illustration:

Items table
[image]

Items Sold
[image]

Sales
[image]

It is obviously trivial to find out what items sold on which day. My challenge is figuring out which items not sold on which day.

I have tried:

```
select i.itemid from items i
where i.ItemID not in ( SELECT         i.ItemID
FROM            Sales d INNER JOIN
                         ItemSold i ON d.SaleDate = i.SaleDate)
```

But that only provides me with the items not sold at all.

I am looking the following result:

[image]

I am using MSSQL.
I have attached the script to recreate the tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [ItemID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemSold](
    [SaleDate] [date] NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
    [SaleDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I would appreciate your help. This is a simplified version of a pretty confusing issue at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first generate all the possible rows -- all dates and all items.  Then use `left join` to filter out the ones that have been sold:

```
select i.itemid, s.saledate
from items i cross join
     sales s left join
     itemsold si
     on si.itemid = i.itemid and si.saledate = s.saledate
where si.itemid is null;
```

Comment: Wow...just like that! Thank you so much!